# Angular & Firebase - How to integrate a search bar that searches a returned firebase list

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

**What I'm using**

- Angular
- Firebase

**What I'm trying to achieve**

- I have a list projects that are returned from firebase
- They are presented in one big list and include metadata such as a thumbnail, title and date
- I would like to include an input field / search bar at the top of the list that would allow me to filter down the list based on title or date (which ever is typed in)
- At some point last year when I briefly took a look at angular, I saw someone add a simple angular attribute to the search box and another on the list and it simply worked. I have no idea if that's the case in Angular2

**Questions**

1. How do I implement a search bar filter in my code below?
2. When trying to filter on a returned list of firebase items, would each search query firebase (something i'd like to avoid), or does it query the items in the DOM client side?

**Note**

- I'm exceptionally new to this stuff and have only been working with angular and firebase for the past month, so any help is massively appreciated here.

**Project Resolver**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AuthService } from '../../user/auth.service';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()

export class ProjectsListResolver {

  constructor(private database: AngularFireDatabase, private authService: AuthService) { }

 
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {

    return Observable.create(observer => {

      this.authService.user
        .first()
        .subscribe(user => {
          this.database.list(`/project_list/${user.uid}`)
            .first()
            .subscribe(projectList => {
              observer.next(projectList);
              observer.complete();
            });
        });
    });
  }

}
```

**Project Component TS**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

// Firebase
import { FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

// Services
import { AuthService } from '../../user/auth.service'
import { NavigationService } from '../../navigation-service/navigation-service.service';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-marketplace',
  templateUrl: './projects-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects-list.component.css']
})


export class ProjectsListComponent implements OnInit {
  projectsList: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    public nav: NavigationService
  ) {}

  


  ngOnInit() {

    // Returns the data from the projects list resolver
    this.activatedRoute.data
      .subscribe((
        data: { projectListData: any }) => {
        this.projectsList = data.projectListData;
      });
  }

  
}
```

**Project Component HTML**

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search for a project..."/>

<ul class="list__ul" *ngIf="projectsList">
  <li class="list__li" *ngFor="let project of projectsList">
    <ul class="list__meta">
    <li>
      <h2 (click)="goToDetailPage(project)"> {{ project.project_title }} </h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span> {{ project.project_date }} </span> 
    </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature was in Angularjs, but not in Angular2+

> Angular doesn't provide pipes for filtering or sorting lists. Developers familiar with AngularJS know these as filter and orderBy. There are no  equivalents in Angular.
>
> This isn't an oversight. Angular doesn't offer such pipes because they perform poorly and prevent aggressive minification. Both filter and orderBy require parameters that reference object properties. Earlier in this page, you learned that such pipes must be impure and that Angular calls impure pipes in almost every change-detection cycle.
>
> Filtering and especially sorting are expensive operations. The user experience can degrade severely for even moderate-sized lists when Angular calls these pipe methods many times per second. filter and orderBy have often been abused in AngularJS apps, leading to complaints that Angular itself is slow. That charge is fair in the indirect sense that AngularJS prepared this performance trap by offering filter and orderBy in the first place.

You could create your own pipe for this: https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: Thanks Notmfb. Good to that it's a difference between angularJS and Angular. However, there's still quite a large portion of my post that I'm stuck on in regards to how to implement it into my code, where in my code, how it integrates with resolvers and firebase etc.

Comment: You could do this on the front-end (not in FB). I haven't used this library before, but you could try it out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-filter-pipe  Or you could simply write a function that is called on (keyup), or you could write your own filter pipe. [Here's an example](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2017/03/16/angular2-creating-custom-search-filter-pipe-for-ngfor-directive/)